# How to calculate the covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, statistical-inference

I tried searching a lot on the net and got the following sources:

[Source One](http://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/covariance-matrix.aspx)

[Source Two](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm)

The first source seems to be incorrect cause when I calculate it using matlab it comes to be different from what they have given as the answer.
As for the second link I cant understand that cause its not completely explaining as to how to calculate. Could anyone please provide me with a sound link or explain how to calculate a co-variance matrix?

Comment: What covariance matrix? The covariance matrix for the OLS estimator is not the same thing as the covariance matrix for the residuals, for example, if we think of a regression context. You need to be more specific. Do you mean sample (co)variance (whose univariate counterpart is $(n-1)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$)?

Comment: I got my answer finally. Have posted it below.

Comment: Where? ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$

Comment: @draks... Bah! Internet problem. Now done!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally understood the concept behind co-variance. Co-variance is different for population data and sample data.

Following is the method I followed:

Let $A$ be a $n \times m$ matrix where $n$ is the number of rows (observations) and $m$ represents the number of columns (variables).
Let $\mathbf e$ be the $n \times 1$ column vector composed entirely of ones. Then,
$$
X= A - \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\mathbf e\mathbf e^TA
$$
Then, denote
$$
Y = X^TX.
$$

Next is the step that differs for population data and sample data.

In case of population data, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is given by :
$$ 
\Sigma=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)Y
$$
and in case of sample data, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is given by :
$$
\Sigma=\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)Y
$$
Hope it helps anyone stuck on a similar problem.

Comment: I've erroneously accepted an edit that was not quite right; now I've tried to edit to adress the confusion that existed prior to this edit. I hope I didn't make things worse.